# Python: split into lines and remove specific line based on search

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, linux, unix

i have a csv file like below, and with my little python knowledge i am trying to split its content into lines based "sec" as start field and remove specific lines which has field with sip:+99*, sip:+88*, sip:+77*.

cat text.csv

```
sec,sip:+1111,2222,3333,4444,5555,sec,6666,sip:+7777,8888,sec,sip:+9999,1000,1100,110,1200,1300,1400
```

required output is lines, where ever string "sec" is matched, and remove specific lines where ever any line with field started with sip:+99*, sip:+88* and sip:+77* (any numbers after sip:+99xxxx)

required output after split:

```
sec,sip:+1111,2222,3333,4444,5555
sec,6666,sip:+7777,8888
sec,sip:+9999,1000,1100,1100,1200,1300,1400
```

required output after removing lines with field match:

```
sec,sip:+1111,2222,3333,4444,5555
```

i have already tried python code using csv, re modules, but no luck.
i am new to python programming, please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def aggr(s):
  " Aggregate into substrings "
  lst = s.split(',')
  current = [lst[0]]
  result = []
  for i in lst[1:]:
    if i == 'sec':
      if current:
        result.append(','.join(current))
        current = []
    current.append(i)
  if current:
    result.append(','.join(current))

  return result

# Input String
s = 'sec,sip:+1111,2222,3333,4444,5555,sec,6666,sip:+7777,8888,sec,sip:+9999,1000,1100,110,1200,1300,1400'

# Aggregate substrings (i.e. substrings starts with 'sec,sip')
l = aggr(s)
print('\n'.join(l))

# Filter out undesired substrings
prefixes = ['sip:+99', 'sip:+88', 'sip:+77']
# only check third column for match of prefixes
result = [i for i in l if not any(x in i.split(',')[2] for x in prefixes)]
print()
print('\n'.join(result))
```

Output

```
sec,sip:+1111,2222,3333,4444,5555
sec,6666,sip:+7777,8888
sec,sip:+9999,1000,1100,110,1200,1300,1400

sec,sip:+1111,2222,3333,4444,5555
sec,sip:+9999,1000,1100,110,1200,1300,1400
```

Comment: Hi Darryl, THANKS a lot, it worked... But i have a small doubt result = [i for i in l if not any(i.startswith('sec,'+x) for x in prefixes)] is written in such a way that if sip+99* is found before "sec," its undesired line. But i have dynamic data which can produce sec,6666,sip:+7777,8888 like, and it is till being printed as sip:+7777 is not before "sec," .. is there any possibility to search only 3rd field and delete the whole line. {sec,6666,sip:+7777,8888} sip+77* found in 3rd field here and whole line can deleted/avoided to print.

Comment: @SSK--believe I made the mod you requested.  It still aggregates lines into strings that begin with sec.  But, now it just checks if the line contains the substring (i.e. sip:+77) rather than following after sec.

Comment: @ssk--you're welcome, but also check out Neda Peyrone solution below as an interesting alternative.

Comment: @DarrylG..thanks, both has different approach but giving my required output. i am currently checking on my own how to print out lines after matching 3rd column,, for example above example looks for +99* anywhere and removes those undesired lines, but it was my mistake to initially ask that way,, my requirement is to remove lines only where 3rd column has match of sip:+99*, sip:+88*,sip:+77* so that i will get only 2 lines output sec,sip:+1111,2222,3333,4444,5555
sec,sip:+9999,1000,1100,1100,1200,1300,1400 (other line has match +77* in 3rd field).

Comment: @ssk--modified so it matches the 3rd column. Only a minor change as you see as noted in the code--i..e. check the line where it generates the result.  Added i.split(',')[2] which retrieves the 3rd column.

Comment: Oops.. really easy.. I am still in learning stage of python basics. :) anyways.  no further requests to you @DarrylG,, really appreciate your help..THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Python:

```
import re
s = 'sec,sip:+1111,2222,3333,4444,5555,sec,6666,sip:+7777,8888,sec,sip:+9999,1000,1100,110,1200,1300,1400'
pos = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('sec', s)]

i = 0
start_idx = end_idx = None

raw_data = []

while i < len(pos)-1:
    start_idx = pos[i]
    end_idx = pos[i+1]-1
    raw_data.append(s[start_idx:end_idx])
    i = i + 1

start_idx = pos[i]
end_idx = len(s)
raw_data.append(s[start_idx:end_idx])
print('%s' % '\n'.join(map(str, raw_data)))

p = re.compile(r'sip:\+(?!([7]{2,}|[8]{2,}|[9]{2,})).*')
result = [ s for s in raw_data if p.search(s) ]
print('\n%s' % '\n '.join(map(str, result)))
```

Output after split:

```
sec,sip:+1111,2222,3333,4444,5555
sec,6666,sip:+7777,8888
sec,sip:+9999,1000,1100,110,1200,1300,1400
```

Output after filter with regular expression:

```
sec,sip:+1111,2222,3333,4444,5555
```